# How to make SVN post-commit hook while using SVN:SSH method

Tags: linux, svn, ssh, centos, svn-hooks

I have a Centos server on which SVN has been configured in SVN+SSH mode. Also website is running on same server. Users work on Windows systems and using Tortoise SVN client to checkout/commit code.

I want whenever a user commit code over SVN from Windows local system it should get updated automatically on the website on Linux server (SVN and website both are on same Linux server). So I was trying to make a post-commit hook. But it is not working.

Location for svn on server is "/var/svn/repos" and location for website is "/var/www/html/website".

Answer (score 1):

1. Post-commit hook (any SVN hook) is running on empty environment, i.e with at least empty PATH. You must to use full-path always inside script of hook
2. Script must have executable bit enabled and (if shell-script used) correct shebang-string
3. Script (user, under which it running: this is ssh-user for connection to server) must have RW-permissions for `/var/www/html/website`

Can't recall any additional problems here.